# Why doesn't gitignore work in this case?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have two files I wish to ignore:

- .idea/workspace.xml
- someapp/src/.idea/workspace.xml

I thought adding this single rule to .gitignore will suffice:

```
.idea/workspace.xml
```

But it only catches the top-level .idea/workspace.xml (git status shows someapp/src/.idea/workspace.xml as untracked).

I also tried `**/.idea/workspace.xml`, but this doesn't work at all. Help?

Comment: Try also ignoring `someapp/src/.idea/workspace.xml`?

Comment: Perhaps *workspace.xml will do?

Comment: @Shahbaz - that works, but I don't understand why .idea/workspace.xml does not.

Comment: @ripper234: Perhaps stuff with slashes in em are considered full paths? btw yo gever

Comment: @yairchu - wassup :) I thought full paths need to start with a slash.

Comment: @chelmertz - it will do, but I thought that .idea/workspace.xml should also do it - and the little pendant inside of me prefers it for the off chance of hitting a workspace.xml file that isn't related to Idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - […]
> - If the pattern does not contain a slash /, git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).
> - Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. […]

As soon as the path contains a slash, Git will no longer check for a match in the path but instead will use the glob behaviour directly. As such, you cannot match for `.idea/workspace.xml` but only for `workspace.xml`.

*[Git manual: gitignore](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html#_pattern_format).*

Comment: @manojlds I hope not… :/ If the pattern does not contain a slash it will match against the pathname, but if it does contain a slash, it will no longer do that and will glob directly.

Comment: yup that's backwards. no slash = glob matching. slash = no glob matching. glob means "* can match a slash"

Comment: NB: this is no longer true for recent versions of git; refer to the answer below for the updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19557737/3064736 is

Answer (score 28):

This has [changed in git 1.8.4](http://git-blame.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/git-184.html)

> Use of platform fnmatch(3) function (many places like pathspec matching, .gitignore and .gitattributes) have been replaced with wildmatch, allowing "foo/**/bar" to match "foo/bar", "foo/a/bar", etc.

`**/.idea/workspace.xml` should work now in this example.

Answer (score 5):

See the examples in gitignore manual:

> "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not
>   "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or **"tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html"**

So `.idea/workspace.xml` will match the root one but not `someapp/src/.idea/workspace.xml`

But depending on your fnmatch implementation, this is what you need in your .gitignore:

```
.idea/workspace.xml
**/.idea/workspace.xml
```

Comment: @ripper234 - Like I said, depends on fnmatch implementation. Works for me.

Comment: I'm on Windows, perhaps this is the reason for the difference.

Comment: Working for me on windows now, specifically the rule `public/**/*.html` is working where `public/*.html` is not.

Answer (score 2):

try this

`/**/.idea/workspace.xml`

Answer (score 0):

According to the gitignore man page:

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. **These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file.** A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

(emphasis mine)