# Difference between ** and * in glob matching (.gitignore)

Tags: git, shell, glob, gitignore

I have the following directory structure and files.

```
pw-spec/
|-- event_spec.coffee
|-- event_spec.js
|-- integration
|   `-- service
|       |-- auth_spec.coffee
|       |-- auth_spec.js
|       |-- chat_spec.coffee
|       |-- chat_spec.js
|       |-- transport_spec.coffee
|       `-- transport_spec.js
|-- message_spec.coffee
|-- message_spec.js
|-- pw_spec.coffee
|-- pw_spec.js
|-- run.coffee
|-- run.html
|-- run.js
|-- service
|   |-- auth_spec.coffee
|   |-- auth_spec.js
|   |-- chat_spec.coffee
|   |-- chat_spec.js
|   |-- stream_spec.coffee
|   `-- stream_spec.js
|-- spec.coffee
|-- spec.js
`-- stub
    |-- stream.coffee
    |-- stream.js
    |-- transport.coffee
    `-- transport.js

4 directories, 27 files
```

I would like to ignore all `*.js` files anywhere within `pw-spec` directory.

However, adding the following patterns to `.gitignore` doesn't cut it:

```
pw-spec/*.js
pw-spec/**/*.js
```

The problem is that the second one only matches js files that are exactly 1 level
deep within the tree, while I want to match all js files under `pw-spec`.

Doing

```
ls pw-spec/**/*.js
```

produces [1]:

```
pw-spec/service/auth_spec.js
pw-spec/service/chat_spec.js
pw-spec/service/stream_spec.js
pw-spec/stub/stream.js
pw-spec/stub/transport.js
```

As you can see

```
pw-spec/integration/service/auth_spec.js
pw-spec/integration/service/chat_spec.js
pw-spec/integration/service/transport_spec.js
```

are missing from [1].

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470664/6309

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that `**` doesn't work, at least not for everyone.  See

[Why doesn't gitignore work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156299/why-doesnt-gitignore-work-in-this-case)

You can have a separate `.gitignore` in `pw-spec/`

Answer (score 9):

There are two approaches for this type of situation, depending on your needs.

One solution is to put

```
# generated files
*.js
```

in pw-spec/.gitignore.

The second solution is to put:

```
/pw-spec/*.js
/pw-spec/*/*.js
/pw-spec/*/*/*.js
```

and so forth in the main .gitignore file.This approach is brittle if more sub-directories are added.

I generally prefer to put the .gitignore file at the same level as the Makefile which generates the files that I am ignoring.

Comment: This solution still works, but as of 2013, you can do exactly what the OP tried: `pw-spec/**/*.js`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470664/5191105).

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.gitignore` in `pw-spec` in which you insert these two lines:

```
*.js
*/*.js
```

Also note that if you already have files tracked in this subdirectory which you want "untracked", you have to make them unknown to the index as such:

```
git rm --cached path/to/file
```

For instance, if in directory `pw-spec` you can do:

```
find -type f -name "*.js" | xargs git rm --cached
```

Comment: I've added `.gitignore` in `pw-spec`. However, `*.js` does match only direct descendants of `pw-spec`, and does not match `.js` files within subdirectories.

Comment: Yeah, I was mixing with `.git/info/exclude`... Hold on

Comment: Hmm, that solves it. I put the `.gitignore` file in the parent of `pw-spec` because there is another dir with similar requirements (I've omitted it for brevity). If I don't find a solution I will simply use 2 `.gitignore` files.

Comment: Maybe try a single .gitignore at the root with 'x/*.js' and 'x/*/*.js' for one directory 'x'? (Note: untested)

Comment: that was my first attempt, and it didn't work. It does not match more than 1 level deep (event with `**`).

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is incorrect. The second line (*/*.js) is completely useless, since it only matches files also matched on the first line.