# Gitignore glob path

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this file hierarchy in my project:

```
assets
  --script.js
  --a.html
  --admin
    --carousel.js
    --documentation.html
```

I want to add rules in .gitignore so that all files inside assets gets ignored except js files. I tried following in .gitignore that only considers script.js from first level:

```
assets
!assets/*.js
```

and then tried this which too only considers script.js  :

```
assets
!assets/**/*.js
```

Other patterns like  !assets/*/*.js or !assets/**.js does not works. I want to consider all javascript files in all levels to consider as untracked.

I am trying this with Git version 2.1.0 .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715898/whats-the-difference-between-git-ignoring-directory-and-directory/25716803#25716803

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between \*\* and \* in glob matching (.gitignore)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832729/difference-between-and-in-glob-matching-gitignore)

Comment: @jubobs -- this does not provides the solution. I tried putting another .gitignore file inside assets folder but that did not worked.

Comment: @jww that is a very old post from 2012 but seems he faced the similar issue. In that post there is no valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not ignore any directories or it will not look into these directories to include `.js` files under them again. Refer to [What's the difference between Git ignoring directory and directory/*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715898/whats-the-difference-between-git-ignoring-directory-and-directory/25716803#25716803).

So the `.gitignore` should be:

```
assets/**
!assets/**/
!assets/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

may be files are already tracked. please untrack other files and add it to your ig

```
# Ignore everything
*
# Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them
!*/
# Don't ignore .gitignore and *.js files
!.gitignore
!*.js
```