# why .gitignore not works?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

my issue is not the same as [Why doesn't gitignore work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156299/why-doesnt-gitignore-work-in-this-case) nor [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working)

files/conf.php is already in .gitignore, but git status still shows its modification, why?

i mean this file should not be tracked if it is in .gitignore...

```
cat .gitignore
files/conf.php
[root@home blogmi]# git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   files/conf.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: If the file is already tracked in the repository I believe it still shows up as changed, regardless of being in the .gitignore

Comment: Are you already tracking `conf.php`?

Answer (score 11):

`.gitignore` only ignores untracked files. Once you've started tracking a file (as you've done with `files/conf.php`), it will not be ignored.

You can use `git rm --cached files/conf.php` to delete the file from git without actually deleting it from the filesystem. After you commit that, the file will start being ignored properly.

Comment: exactly. From what I understand, you've already at one point 'added' and staged the file to be ready for a commit. Even if you add it to the .gitignore it wont be ignored until you run the command @KevinBallard suggested above. Then, it will not be included.

Comment: One question I have is, if you unstage the file, and add it to the .gitignore...If you then say `git add <that file>` will it add it?

Comment: @iight: It's not staged for commit. The file is actually already committed and tracked by the repo, but contains unstaged changes. Not that it matters much. And in your second question, `git add` will actually ignore the file (and I believe it will tell you that it skipped the file). You have to use `git add -f $file` to make it work.