# Cannot ignore .idea/workspace.xml - keeps popping up

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Using PHPStorm, I am trying to ignore the `workspace.xml` which pops up every-time I try to make a git commit.

My `.gitignore` looks like:

```
/.idea/
.idea/workspace.xml
```

Because at a point the file was committed, I've also executed:

`git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml` and then committed the removal, pushed to a bare repo.

But the file keeps popping up later when I do changes in the project.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Tried everything below, added to gitignore, but it still keeps coming back, ignoring gitignore.

Comment: Looks like [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156299/why-doesnt-gitignore-work-in-this-case). Check it out and see...

Comment: Chek out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156299/why-doesnt-gitignore-work-in-this-case. Looks like your same problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had to:

- remove the file from git
- push the commit to all remotes
- make sure all other committers updated from remote

Commands

```
git rm -f .idea/workspace.xml
git remote | xargs -L1 git push --all
```

Other committers should run

```
git pull
```

Comment: While I'm glad for this answer, I can't help but feel that it would be more useful if the instructions of how to accomplish the steps (eg, command line directives) were included.

Comment: Chek out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156299/why-doesnt-gitignore-work-in-this-case.

Looks exactly like your same problem.

Comment: shut down IDE \n git rm -f .idea/workspace.xml \n git commit -m "removing workspace.xml" \n edit .gitignore to exclude workspace.xml \n open IDE

Answer (score 327):

I was facing the same issue, and it drove me up the wall. The issue ended up to be that the .idea folder was ALREADY commited into the repo previously, and so they were being tracked by git regardless of whether you ignored them or not. I would recommend the following, after closing RubyMine/IntelliJ or whatever IDE you are using:

```
mv .idea ../.idea_backup
rm .idea # in case you forgot to close your IDE
git rm -r .idea 
git commit -m "Remove .idea from repo"
mv ../.idea_backup .idea
```

After than make sure to ignore .idea in your .gitignore

Although it is sufficient to ignore it in the repository's .gitignore, I would suggest that you ignore your IDE's dotfiles globally.

Otherwise you will have to add it to every .gitgnore for every project you work on. Also, if you collaborate with other people, then its best practice not to pollute the project's .gitignore with private configuation that are not specific to the source-code of the project.

Comment: The last command should be "mv ../.idea_backup .idea" instead of "git mv ../.idea_backup .idea" to avoid git error

Comment: I have to do `git rm .idea` instead of `git add .idea` to do the job

Comment: I also changed `add` for `rm` but in my case I had to add `-r` as well to recursively remove all. `git rm -r .idea`

Comment: Wow... thank you!! Tried this a million different ways to no avail. THIS is the correct step by step approach. The key difference that I was missing was to make sure my IDE was closed - don't miss that step! Excellent answer :)

Comment: Thanks! many, many time spent looking for a working solutions and tried severals. This is the simplest way to do that.

Comment: This works for anything in your .gitignore that is already tracked.

Comment: Found no solution to this, until reading this, thanks for the solution.

Although ensure you have no stashes of the .idea folder as this would require you to delete the stash.

Comment: Months later... I tried this and it worked. I believe this should marked as the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful but I would want to change `rm .idea` to `rm -rf .idea`.

Comment: Wow, do people still actually waste their time with this stuff? Something like GitKraken can get this done for you in a second.

Answer (score 94):

I had this problem just now, I had to do `git rm -f .idea/workspace.xml`
now it seems to be gone (I also had to put it into `.gitignore`)

Comment: I would also add, only for precision sake, that Idea intellij should be closed when doing this steps.

Answer (score 32):

To remove `.idea/` completely from the git **without affecting your IDE** config you could just do:

```
git rm -r --cached '.idea/'
echo .idea >> .gitignore
git commit -am "removed .idea/ directory"
```

Answer (score 29):

In the same dir where you see the file appear do:

- `rm .idea/workspace.xml`
- `git rm -f .idea/workspace.xml (as suggested by chris vdp)`
- `vi .gitignore`
- <kbd>i</kbd> (to edit), add `.idea/workspace.xml` in one of the lines, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, `:wq`

You should be good now

Comment: Or, to add the row to .gitignore, just type `echo .idea/workspace.xml>>.gitignore`. You don't need to open vi for everything. Alternatively, and what would I would do, is to have a separate .gitignore file in the .idea directory: `echo workspace.xml>>.idea/.gitignore`

Answer (score 8):

If you have **multiple projects** in your git repo, `.idea/workspace.xml` will not match to any files.

Instead, do the following:

`$ git rm -f **/.idea/workspace.xml`

And make your .gitignore look something like this:

```
# User-specific stuff:
**/.idea/workspace.xml
**/.idea/tasks.xml
**/.idea/dictionaries
**/.idea/vcs.xml
**/.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
**/.idea/dataSources.ids
**/.idea/dataSources.xml
**/.idea/dataSources.local.xml
**/.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
**/.idea/dynamic.xml
**/.idea/uiDesigner.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

# IntelliJ
/out/
```

Answer (score 6):

**Just tell git to not assume it is changed never matter what:**

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/file/to/ignore
```

yes, you can remove the files from the git repository. But if your team all use the same IDE or you are by yourself, you probably don't want to do that. For yourself, you want to have an ok starting point to resume working, for your teammates as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way i did in Android Studio which is also based on IntelliJ was like this. In commit dialog, I reverted the change for workspace.xml, then it was moved to unversioned file. After that I deleted this from commit dialog. Now it won't appear in the changelist. Note that my gitignore was already including .idea/workspace.xml

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me with PHPStorm

Finally I solved doing the following:

- Remove **.idea/** directory
- Move **.gitignore** to the same level will be the new generated **.idea/**
- Write the files you need to be ignored, and **.idea/** too. To be sure it will be ignored I put the following:

  - .idea/
  - .idea
  - .idea/*

I don't know why works this way, maybe **.gitignore** need to be at the same level of **.idea** to can be ignored this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since in my case I was performing a first commit of a project, simply deleting `.git` and `.idea` folders and then reinitializing git using `git init` helped to solve a problem. Now I don't have `.idea` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unintuitive but so easy to fix once I figured it out: I added the file to .gitignore, then reverted that file in the Commit tab's changelist.  It no longer appeared.

(I'm guessing that once the change is automatically added to git by IntelliJ, it no longer will compare against .gitignore.  Once reverted, IntelliJ will start comparing against .gitignore before adding the file.)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought i'd share my experience with this.

I had the same issue no matter what I tried but turns the repo I was working on generated a .idea on the top level as you'd expect, but the `.gitignore` was placed within a folder lower down the directory tree.

So:

```
.idea // On the level above the .gitignore file
application/
- .gitignore // too low to include .idea
- otherfile.js
```

So my solution was that I needed to create a `.gitignore` file at the top level of the repo, I was then able to delete / the .idea folder as expected, like so:

```
.gitignore // Now this can successfully target .idea below
.idea
application/
- .gitignore
- otherfile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
mv .idea ../.idea_backup
rm .idea # in case you forgot to close your IDE
git rm -r .idea 
git commit -m "Remove .idea from repo"
mv ../.idea_backup .idea
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

Ignore the files ending with `.iws`, and the `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` files in your .gitignore
[Reference](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)