# Android studio - gitignore file

Tags: android, git, gitignore

i just started to use git and i created .gitignore file, after i do changes in one of the java files i see that the git not ignore from files that suppose to ignored. for example:
[image]

only the Logger.java suppose to be committed and the two other files not.

this is my .gitignore file:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml

# Keystore files
*.jks
```

Comment: I think you took your gitignore file here: https://www.gitignore.io/api/android but you never mention to ignore these two files

Answer (score 0):

I think you took your gitignore file here: [gitignore.io/api/android](https://www.gitignore.io/api/android) but you never mention to ignore these two files... 
Maybe you should add these two lines in your .gitingore

```
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/misc.xml
```

If you already commited your files, you will probably have to remove these files from you git. 
See this post: [Cannot ignore .idea/workspace.xml - keeps popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973506/cannot-ignore-idea-workspace-xml-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: I personally use these for my android studio ignore files:
# Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA 
*.iws
.idea/libraries
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/gradle.xml

Comment: I just give those files for example, sometimes appears between 15- 20 files and i can't add all of them to the .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `.idea` to the ignored list:

```
# Add it with the / at the end (since you want to ignore all the folder)
.idea/

# Now remove the files you have already added to the repo
git rm --cached .idea/*
```

Those files are generated by JetBrain products (in your case android studio IDE) and you have to mark the folder as ignored.