# Git: Avoid IDE config files to go on remote server

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm working on a local project with PhpStorm. When I do commits & push with Git, it also takes the `.idea` folder and I don't want it.

I added the `.idea` folder in the `.gitignore` file, but after that :

1. The folder was removed remotely (Good)
2. When other developers (who also use PhpStorm) take changes on the remote, `.idea` is deleted on their local machine, PhpStorm does not recognize the project folders and does not track the changes of the files anymore (Bad)

On a blog I discovered the command `git update-index --skip-worktree </path/to/file>` that ignores changes made locally on a file. It works but the problem with this command is that I have to apply it on every file I want to ignore. PhpStorm regularly creates many files in `.idea` and I don't want to manually ignore every single one of them before committing & pushing.

My question is this: Is there a Git command/script or PhpStorm tool that would allow me to :

1. Keep a folder only locally for the IDE/local environment
2. Ignore this folder and any files it contains when I commit & push

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069336/8020009. The second part of your problem is quite strange, please check if it reoccurs after trying the suggestion I've linked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try